# How do I install vapor-retarder underlayment paper under vinyl floor planks?

Tags: flooring, vapor-barrier, underlayment

Do I overlap the sheets of paper or are the seams supposed to lay flat against each other? Is it okay to use nails to hold it down, or does it have to be stapled?  Can I use silicone to seal the seams?

Answer (score 1):

We usually staple down the flooring paper just enough to keep it from shifting, then flatten the staples with a hammer or the back of the stapler. We overlap the rows by about 4 inches and tape the seams with Tyvec tape.